# OnClickListener and Table Layout

Tags: java, android, arrays, button, onclicklistener

I have an Activity with two layouts, both implemented in R.layout.main. The first one is a Relative Layout with the app's main screen, and the other is a Table Layout, holding a kind of Preferences Screen. Normally, the first one is set to visible, and the second one to gone. By clicking a button I make the Relative Layout gone, and the Table Layout visible. 
And here starts my problem, I wanted to set a OnClickListener to that Table Layout (which is actually an array of buttons). 
I tried something like:

```
final TableLayout table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tab);
    table.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View arg){
             Button clickedButton = (Button)arg;
             String t = (String) clickedButton.getTag();

             Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),t,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
             toast.show();

        }
    });
```

Obviously, it doesn't work. 
I'm quite new to Android programming, and I've been looking for a suitable solution for the whole day without any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It couldn't work because you are first trying to cast a TableLayout to a button... 
if your TableLayout is only containing buttons you could do something like:

```
TableLayout yourRootLayout = findView....
int count = yourRootLayout.getChildCount();
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
    View v = yourRootLayout.getChildAt(i);
    if(v instanceof TableRow){
        TableRow row = (TableRow)v;
        int rowCount = row.getChildCount();
        for (int r = 0; r < rowCount; r++){
            View v2 = row.getChildAt(r);
            if (v2 instanceof Button){
                Button b = (Button)v2;
                b.setOnClickListener(this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and let your activity implement OnClickListener. Just copy your Existing onClick into Activity itself...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, I maybe made it a little bit unclear. I have a Table Layout consisting of 5 rows, 4 buttons in each. Eventually it is an array consisting of buttons only, however, your method returns the Table Row as Child, so the OnClickListener still doesn't work properly. Do you have any idea to improve that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It works perfectly. Wouldn't figure that out myself for another week, I guess. Thank you very very much.