# onClickListener on TableLayout

Tags: android

I faced with trivial problem but i don't know how to solve it. I have several `ImageView`s on my TableLayout how can i create one onClickListner for all of them. It should looks like this :

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case(R.id.imageStart):
    {
        this.startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,GameActivity.class));
        break;
    }
    case(R.id.imageExit):
    {
        finish();
        break;
    }

    }

}
```

If it's possible or course, i am new in Android Dev. I saw sample where for each ImageView have his own onClickListner but its not a good practice i suppose. Thanks.

Comment: public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    .......  code
    }  Are you using this.. And also show your more used code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603868/android-onclicklistener-and-table-layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow this Steps :

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implement OnClickListener{

@override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   //get the View  by Id
   ImageView img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img1);
   ImageView img2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img2);
   ImageView img3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img3);

   //set the OnClickListener on your ImageViews
   img1.setOnClickListener(this);
   img2.setOnClickListener(this);
   img3.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@override
public void onClick(View v){
   switch(v.getId()){
       case(R.id.img1):
         Toast.makeText(this,"image 1 clicked ...",3000).show();
         break;
       case(R.id.img2):
         Toast.makeText(this,"image 2 clicked ...",3000).show();
         break;
       case(R.id.img3):
         Toast.makeText(this,"image 3 clicked ...",3000).show();
         break;
   }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that. Just implement the OnClickListener in your class:

> public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
>
> }

Add your onClick method to that class and then all you have to do for each button is this:

> button.setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: if that the only way, maybe we can get collection of elements in TableView and add one time onClickListner or maybe i just dreaming???

Comment: I've never really used a table but maybe there's a onRowClickListener or something like that?!
Or maybe you can use a ListView instead of a TableLayout. Then you could add an onItemClickListener or add a clickListener in your getView in your adapter. Then you just have to add it once and it will be used for each row.

Comment: you will set onClickListener on any buttons that you have, and then implement the Method onClick() , so then you can switch the id of your buttons to define which action to execute , and i'm so sorry for my bad English :)