# Adding TableRow programmatically in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I'm working in an Android application and I want to add a TableRow programmatically in my TableLayout.

I have this TableLayout:

```
<TableLayout
android:id="@+id/details_table"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:text="4686"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="7px"
        android:textColor="@color/black"  />
    <TextView
        android:text="sdhiuf osdfh isdhf ihdf"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="7px"
        android:textColor="@color/black"  />
    <TextView
        android:text="2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="7px"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />
    <TextView
        android:text="UN"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="7px"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />
</TableRow>
```

and I want to add this exactly TableRow programmatically.

I'm trying something like this:

```
TableLayout detailsTable = (TableLayout) l.findViewById(R.id.details_table);

for(Nfce_Product nfceProduct : nfceProducts){
    TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(getActivity());

    TextView tvProductCode = new TextView(getActivity());
    tvProductCode.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
    tvProductCode.setText(nfceProduct.getProduct_code());
    tvProductCode.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, productDetailsTextSize);
    tvProductCode.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));

    TextView tvProductDescription = new TextView(getActivity());
    tvProductDescription.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
    tvProductDescription.setText(nfceProduct.getProduct_description());
    tvProductDescription.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, productDetailsTextSize);
    tvProductDescription.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));

    TextView tvProductAmount = new TextView(getActivity());
    tvProductAmount.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
    tvProductAmount.setText(String.valueOf(nfceProduct.getAmount()));
    tvProductAmount.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, productDetailsTextSize);
    tvProductAmount.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));

    TextView tvProductMetric = new TextView(getActivity());
    tvProductMetric.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
    tvProductMetric.setText(nfceProduct.getProduct_metric());
    tvProductMetric.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, productDetailsTextSize);
    tvProductMetric.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));

    tableRow.addView(tvProductCode);
    tableRow.addView(tvProductDescription);
    tableRow.addView(tvProductAmount);
    tableRow.addView(tvProductMetric);
    detailsTable.addView(tableRow);
}
```

Comment: One other thing, you're going to need a layout height for each of your text views.

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: The tableRow are just not showing up

Comment: Can we see more of your code - like how you are declaring the table and the xml placing the table in a layout?  Are you sure the table is showing up?

Comment: You didn't include everything, am wondering where you are getting detailsTable? Is that from a findviewbyid or similar or is that created programtically too? Also, assuming product detailsTextSize is 7?

Comment: I edited the post, i added more lines of my code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Here is my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11672832/1316483) to my own dynamically created `TableRow` question. I think my answer is detailed enough, you should have no problems taking it as your own! My issue involved not only dynamically creating `TableRows`, but also being able to touch each row and have something happen. I've gone further than that nowadays to make each CELL separately clickable.

Edit: You need to have a separate `TableRow` `XML` file that you can access, separate from the actual `TableLayout` you're trying to dynamically populate.

Edit2: I should probably try to make an actual solution for you, so that you see what I'm talking about:

First, create (or keep) your `XML` file containing your `TableLayout`. Second, Create a separate `TableRow` `XML` file.

(This is your potential tablerow.xml file)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:focusable="true" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tableCell1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="7px"
        android:textColor="@color/black"  />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tableCell2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="7px"
        android:textColor="@color/black"  />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tableCell3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="7px"
        android:textColor="@color/black"  />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tableCell4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="7px"
        android:textColor="@color/black"  />
</TableRow>
```

Now... back to your actual code!

```
for (Nfce_Product nfceProduct : nfceProducts) {
    final TableLayout detailsTable = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.details_table);
    final TableRow tableRow = (TableRow) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tablerow, null);
    TextView tv;

    //Filling in cells
    tv = (TextView) tableRow.findViewById(R.id.tableCell1);
    tv.setText(nfceProduct.getProduct_code());

    tv = (TextView) tableRow.findViewById(R.id.tableCell2);
    tv.setText(nfceProduct.getProduct_description());

    tv = (TextView) tableRow.findViewById(R.id.tableCell3);
    tv.setText(nfceProduct.getAmount());

    tv = (TextView) tableRow.findViewById(R.id.tableCell4);
    tv.setText(nfceProduct.getProduct_metric());

    //Add row to the table
    detailsTable.addView(tableRow);
} //End for
```

If you still need/want to change the text size and color, you can do that after the `setText()` line and before you do `findViewById` again. If you want to have column headers that basically say Code, Description, Amount, and Metric, make a `TableRow` inside the `TableLayout` like you have currently. The `TableRows` created programmatically will fall in line after that "header" row.